# Access Array of textbox id's. in Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm new to jquery.
I have a MVC code which is a form having textboxes with id's from 0 to n. There is an add button, on clicking it an extra text box is created and continues until user wishes to add as many text boxes as he can. Now I want to convert the text inside text boxes from lowercase to uppercase using jquery. I know how to do for a single text box, but how can i access when the textbox id's are in for loop. Here is an example of my text box id's

```
<input type="text" id="txt[i]", value = "box[i]">
```

i value varies from 0 to n as long as user wants to insert n no. of text boxes dynamically.

PS: I'm newbie to Stackoverflow too. Please dont mind for code format as idk how to post code here.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Selim, but it didn't solve my prob. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can select textboxes by `class` instead of `id`, and use [`jQuery.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), so that you don't need to know id's.

First adding class attribute:

```
<input class="tbUpperClass" type="text" id="txt[i]" value="box[i]">
```

Then script would be like:

```
$(".tbUpperClass").each(function (index, value) {
    var text = $(this).val();

    //Converting text to uppercase and set textbox value
    $(this).val(text.toUpperCase());

});
```

See: [Jquery class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)